# Tomcat 5.5 - multiple contexts using same path

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting, contextpath

Is it possible to set up multiple contexts using the same path?  For example:

```
<Context docBase="/www/websites/site1/java/base" path="/base" reloadable="true"/>
<Context docBase="/www/websites/site2/java/base" path="/base" reloadable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. How would the container know which context should handle a request beginning with `/base`?

Comment: That's my point.  I have two sites that use the same path running on the same server.  I have no control over the structure of the sites because they are maintained by a client.  Until now, they have been content with only allowing one site to run at a time, but this is a major hassle.  I understand why it doesn't work, but I need to know if there's a workaround.

Comment: Are you talking about virtual hosts, where the server sniffs out the requested hostname and dispatches based on that? Anyway, it looks to me like this question belongs on ServerFault.